# From localhost to server

Tags: reactjs, jsx

hi everyone I'm begginer on React and that's why I cant understand this thing
if it's possible, how can I place created React project (with command "npx create-react-app /name/") to own server, for example, to ospanel?
I have to replace project from localhost to really existing server

I tried to do this with Next.js and changing basePath, nothing happened.